Can you give me an intuative understanding of the measure of curvature: "4 1/mm"?
Update: Follow up questions:

Why is the reciprocal of the radius deemed more descriptive of the curvature that the radius itself?
Who uses these 1/mm (or I assume 1/m or even 1/") measures of curvature?
How do the use them?
What do they use them for.(Beyond a simple statement of "measuring curves":)

END-OF-UPDATE
In my CAD software, a curve that started out in 2D as an ellipse of a known size, once it has been manipulated (rotated, pulled to a solid etc.) is now represented by a closed spline; and the best information the CAD system can give me is of the form:
Edge length: 125.93180563mm, Max curvature: 7.8125 1/mm, Min curvature: 0.0033618 1/mm
The above example started out as an ellipse with a length of 62.5mm and a width of 4mm. (You can use Major axis and Minor axis if you like; but I won't be!)
A (non-circular) ellipse has "sharp" curves at each end of the long side (length), and "shallow" curves at each end of the short side (width). And I can assume that one of the max or min values relates to one (pair) of those and the other to the other pair. But I have no understanding of which is which; or what those numerical values, in units of 1/mm, actually mean.
And my attempts to find relevant explanations on the web range from "Its a unit of curvature"!, to fascinating treatise on the anuses (anusii?) of Bluegilled Sunfish; to diatribes on elliptical functions and some guy called Riemann who was apparently very clever; all of which is entirely useless information in my world.
So, can anyone explain the units "nn.nnn 1/mm" such that I might (for example) be able to guestimate the min and max curvature of the handle of my coffee mug that goes from being almost straight at the bottom and decreases in (for want of a better term) instantaneous radius, until it is pretty nearly (a quadarent of) a 30mm radius circle at the top.
Have at me :)

If you fit a circle to the curve as best as possible at a point, its radius' units may be in $mm$. The curvature is one over the radius of this circle. Hence units of $1/mm$

So that's 'the reciprocal of the radius of the best fit circle at a point on a line, is the "curvature" of that line at that point'. Hm. I can see me using that every day.

regarding q1: it makes sense for a flatter curve to have a smaller curvature, since it is less curved (duh), and a flatter curve has a larger radius, so radius is no good. A standard trick to make a new variable get smaller while the original gets bigger is to look at the inverse.

Having seen David P's answer, and done some (a lot) of emperical investigation (in my CAD package), this is what I think constitutes a full answer to my question:
In the following image, the black ellipse has dimensions of 69.51 x 50mm. This curve can (is) characterised as having maximum and minimum curvatures of 0.05560654 1/mm and 0.02083225 1.mm respectively.
This means that the software has determined (by some process?) that:
i) the 'best fit' circle to the curve at either end of the minor axis has a radius of 48.002493825; and 1/48.002493825 = 0.02083225100024269416173400236878; so that is the Minimum curvature of the curve.
ii) the 'best fit' circle to the curve at either end of the major axis has a radius of 17.98349586; and 1/17.98349586 = 0.05560654, so that is the maximum curvature of the curve.

Please see my OP for follow up questions.

It appears you've answered your question to your own satisfaction (+1), but to address the curious-looking units: Suppose we have a unit-speed plane curve $c$. (Originally I denoted this with gamma ($\gamma$), the third letter of the Greek alphabet.) Concretely, $c(s)$ is a point in the plane for each real $s$ in some open interval, and $|c'(s)| = 1$ for all $s$ (the path $c$ has unit speed).
We may view the velocity $T(s) := c'(s)$ as a unit vector at the point $p = c(s)$, the heading at $p$. To measure "how curved is $c$ at the point $p$?", it's natural to measure how rapidly the heading changes per unit length at $p$:

The units of this quantity are radians per unit length, i.e., reciprocal of length.
Unsigned curvature $\kappa$ is the numerical measure. In symbols, $\kappa(s) = |T'(s)| = |c''(s)|$. (N.B. To emphasize, these formulas assume $c$ has unit speed.)

For a circle of radius $r$, the heading changes by $2\pi$ radians (one full turn in the plane) over an arc length $2\pi r$ (the circumference). Since the rate of change of heading is constant per unit length, the curvature of a circle is the ratio: $(2\pi)/(2\pi r) = 1/r$ in $r$'s length units.
The animation shows an ellipse with aspect ratio $3 \times 1$ and 60 unit velocity vectors evenly-spaced by distance along the ellipse. Qualitatively, the curvature (in radians per mm) is largest where successive arrows' directions change most rapidly in radians per mm (left and right ends) and smallest where successive arrows are most nearly parallel (top and bottom).


Thankyou for your response. Unfortunately (or possibly fortunately), I don't understand a word of it. Or rather, I completely understand every word (osculting had me scratching my head), individually; just not the meaning when they are strung together in that particular sequence. Tautologies aside, and preferably without the weird, roughly Y shaped squiggles, and the need for italisised phrases. Care to try and explain this to a non classical mathematician?

BTW: Where did 'p' come from (in "how curved is γ at p?") it has neither previous nor further reference?????

When curvature is very small, it means that the curve is practically similar to a straight line, and radius is very high. So it is more intuitive to measure the curvature not with radius, but with the opposite of radius.

The mention of osculating ("best fit") circles was intended to anchor things in the familiar. Since that paragraph had the opposite effect, it seemed worth removing. I hope the animation helps. My intent is merely to explain why "per mm" is a natural unit to measure curvature, why a larger value corresponds to a sharper turn.

@AndrewD.Hwang Thankyou for accommodating me. However, I do not understand why you introduced 'speed', 'velocity' and 'unit' versions of them into this. The ellipse in my case is the edge of a piece af plactic and doesn't move. I reproduced your animation: https://ibb.co/0JBsjG8 by simply drawing 60 equispaced half tangents around the ellipse. My problem with "per mm" is that by the time you've moved 1mm (or just 0.0001mm), the curvature has already changed. I'm failing (planetary orbits aside) to see how it is useful. (I AM trying to though.)

That's a fair assessment. Not sure I have a better answer than "introducing (abstract, imaginary) motion gives us conceptual scaffolding to study and interpret shape," here using intuition about velocity to avoid speaking explicitly of limits and derivatives. We can eliminate motion-language, but I don't see how to explain the "per mm" units without something like calculus (limits and derivatives). <> Please do feel free to disregard this answer if it's not helpful! :)
